# Nodejs Service returning datetime instead of just date when trying to cast datetime field to date of a SQL Server Query

Tags: node.js, sql-server

My database is SQL Server. I have the following sql query
`SELECT RQI,RQIOver,PCI,PCIOver,PQI,PQIOver,SR,SROver,IRI,IRIOver,RUT,RUTOver,cast(DateCollected as date) as DateCollected,cast(DateCollectedOver as date) as DateCollectedOver from dbo.PF_Condition where SegmentId=12665`

The result I am getting for DateCollected is just the date, which I need, when run it in SQL Management Studio. However when I put the same SQL query in a nodejs service which I created the result is not the same. 
I needed to extract YYYY-MM-DD from datetime field DateCollected and DateCollectedOver as mentioned in the query above. 
Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Not the same how?  What's the expected value and what are you getting instead?

Comment: When I run the same query in the nodejs service it is returning me the value of datetime not just the date.

Comment: Is the result being saved as a js date object? Because that will show a time part by default

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with the slice operator of javascript and sliced the date part only and displayed in the frontend where I need to. The results returned are of type string so the slice operator worked. 
If someone can help why the cast function is not working in the sql query when I put it in the nodejs service it will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

After casting as DATE, you can then use the LEFT function to truncate the result to 10 characters:

```
LEFT(cast(DateCollected as date), 10) as DateCollected
```

which would return a string with the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'